# What exactly is the meaning of nvarchar(n)

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar

The documentation isn't super clear: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

What happens if I try to store a 20 character length string in a column defined as nvarchar(10)?  Is 10 the max length the field could be or is it the expected length?  If I can exceed n characters in the string, what are the performance implications of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of characters you can store in a column or variable typed as `nvarchar(n)` is `n`. If you try to store more your string will be truncated, or in case of an insert into a table, the insert would be disallowed with a warning about possible truncation:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

```
declare @n nvarchar(10)
set @n = N'more than ten chars'
select @n
```

Result:

```
----------
more than 

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: If inserting data into a table and you try to put more than 10 characters, you will receive an error `String or binary data would be truncated` and not be able to insert the data.

Comment: @RickS True. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, nvarchar will only only store the provided characters up to the amount defined. Nchar will actually fill in the unused characters with whitespace.